# Recovering data from a SSD that now appears to be FAT32

Tags: partitioning, ssd, data-recovery

I know there are a lot of threads on here about recovering data from bad drives in general (or SSDs in particular), but I'm in a particular situation that I'm trying to understand in terms of next steps.

About a week ago, my Samsung T1 Portable (an encrypted 1TB SSD connecting through USB 3) started showing as RAW/unreadable in Windows 10. (The Samsung application that provides encryption access still worked fine.) Changing ports and machines produced the same result. I did a LOT of reading up on recovery, trying various sites and applications. I ran a number of "deep scans" with varying degrees of success, but did not actually proceed to recovery (in part because none of the scans produced great results).

I kept reading, looking for insight I couldn't find: was recovery the only option? Wasn't it just a bad partition table? etc.

Which led me to yesterday, unwisely following advice that said to run a CHKDSK operation with /r /f options on the "unformatted" volume. It found some "lost chains" and repaired them... which led me to a single FAT32 partition, 124MB, with nothing on it, and now various deep scans are mostly finding... that partition.

Specific questions:

1. What did CHKDSK do? I know it's a no-no to write to an SSD that one
   hopes to recover, is that what happened?
2. Some recovery applications show it as still having an unformatted 1TB volume, but scanning doesn't find files, just fragments and very few of them. Is there a
   simple explanation for that?
3. Is there a canonical resource for how
   to handle an SSD recovery correctly? There are certainly lots of
   discussions?

I'd assume the drive is toast, but would love to understand better what I SHOULD have done.

Comment: An SSD that supports TRIM is already impossible to save deleted data, but when the data is also encrypted this is absolutely impossible. You should never encrypt data that you may need to salvage later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. CHKDSK using /F writes correction to the disk and that could have caused the damage you see. Better to run CHKDSK without parameters to see the condition but that is too late now.

2 and 3. If the data is really important you may need to see if a local recovery agency can help you. I think this is all you can do now.